# Kernel Crashes due to OOM error (USB_SUBMIT_URB)

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, usb, kernel, linux-device-driver

Scenario :

I am calling usb_submit_urb in ioctl call to send audio packets from the application.
Code implementation is as follows :

> > ```
> > retval = copy_from_user(&pkt_1722, pkt_1722_userspace, 
> >                         sizeof(struct ifr_data_struct_1722));
> > if(retval) {
> >     printk("copy_from_user error: pkt_1722\n");
> >     retval = -EINVAL;
> > }
> > usb_init_urb(bky_urb_alloc[bky_urb_context.bky_i]);
> > usb_fill_bulk_urb(bky_urb_alloc[bky_urb_context.bky_i],
> >                   dev->udev,
> >                   priv->avb_a_out,
> >                   (void*) dma_buf[bky_urb_context.bky_i],
> >                   112,
> >                   bky_write_bulk_callback,
> >                   &bky_urb_context); 
> > retval = usb_submit_urb(bky_urb_alloc[bky_urb_context.bky_i],
> >                         GFP_ATOMIC);
> > if (retval) {
> >     printk(KERN_INFO "%s - failed submitting write urb, error %d",
> >            __FUNCTION__, retval);
> >     goto error;
> > }
> > ```

I am maintaining an array of urbs so that I can reuse them after their completion handlers get called. The allocation of urb and dma_buf takes place once in probe.

Problem :

I am able to stream 1722 packets for few hours and after that kernel crashes and I can only see the black screen with the call traces and says OOM error (Out of memory). The PID that caused the error is some other kernel process running in the background which tries to allocate pages
but it fails and shows OOM and kernel crashes.
May be this problem is due to the external fragmentation that takes place over the period of time.
Any inputs will be of great help.

Comment: Can calling usb_submit_urb consecutively for few hours can cause fragmentation of memory ?

Answer (score 0):

1)  Are the USB urb&s being consumed by something?  Whoever has the pointer to the block is responsible for passing it on or freeing the buffer.

2)  Have you set the `vm.min_free_kbytes` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to at least 1% of system memory?

3)  While the system runs, capture `/proc/slabinfo` in a shell loop and see if there is a leak somewhere.